# How to create action for mulitple view button (submit) in one controller in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm not able to perform action for button from second view, my folder path look like this:

```
   --Controllers
   ----LoginController
   --Models
   ----LoginModel
   --Views
   ----Login
   ------Login.cshtml
   ----Home.cshtml
```

In one controller I created 2 actions: one is Login and another is home. In Login view I created a button. When I click on it take to the controller, but when I click from home view it does nothing...

Comment: post your html button code

Comment: you need to move Home.chtml in to Login folder first.

Comment: make sure that both views are in same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
home.cshtml
@using (Html.BeginForm("Home", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
<input  type='submit'  value='Save' id='btnSave'>
}
Login.cshtml
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
<input  type='submit'  value='Save' id='btnSave'>
}
```